# Setting -classpath in bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, javac

I am trying to create a compile.bat file using the following classes: HumanTest (main method), Man, Food. Below are the code for the 3 classes. In this situation Food is already compiled and I do not have the .java file for it.

```
package human.man;

public class Man {

    private String name;
    private Food f;

    public Man(String name, Food f) {
        this.name = name;
        this.f = f;
    }
}

public class Food {
    private String foodName;

    public Food(String name) {
        foodName = name;
    }
}

import human.man.*;
public class HumanTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Food f = new Food("ckt");
        Man m = new Man("joe", f);
    }
}
```

In compile.bat, i run the following code
`javac -cp classes;src HumanTest.java`
But I get the error that Food class cannot be found. I'm wondering why this is so even though I have already set the classpath for Food.class. Here's the link for the files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wussnm55tbnh3t/Question.zip?dl=0

EDIT:
Below is the tree diagram, do let me know if I drew it incorrectly!

```
--Question
  |--compile.bat
  |--HumanTest.java
  |--classes
     |--Food.class
  |--src
     |--human
        |--man
           |--Man.java
```

Comment: Could you diagram the directories you're using, and where your `.java` and `.class` files are?

Comment: Put it in a jar, maybe? Who distributes .class files anyways?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to batch files, but purely on the organization of your classes. You can't import a default package from a named package, nor can you use a class that is in the default package from a class that is in a named package.

In class human.man.Man, you are trying to use class Food which is in the default package. Try moving Food to a named package instead.

Comment: If I don't have the Food.java file to edit, does this mean that I won't be able to compile this at all?

Comment: You will be able to compile it, but only if your classes are themselves in the default namespace. This is why it's not recommended to use the default namespace. The person who wrote Food.class is forcing you to put your classes in the default namespace if you want to use his class. Which is not nice.